# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.db.list(...).map is not a function TypeError: this.db.list(...).map is not a function

Tags: angular, firebase, observable

> error ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.db.list(...).map is not a function TypeError: this.db.list(...).

map is not a function may be the error in mapping I DONT KNOW WHY FIREBASE LIST OBSERVABLE NOT MAPPING WITH OBSERVABLE PROPERLY

```js
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";

export class employee {

  constructor(
  public $key:string,
  public age:number,
  public username: string,
  public email:string,
  public yoe:number
  )

  {}

    //   static fromJsonList(array): employee[] {
    //         return array.map(employee.fromJson);
    //     }

    // static fromJson({$key,age,username,email,yoe}):employee {
    //     return new employee(
    //         $key,age,username,email,yoe);
    // }
    static fromJson({$key, age,username,email,yoe}) {
        return new employee($key, age,username,email,yoe);
    }
        static fromJsonArray(json : any[]) : employee[] {
        return json.map(employee.fromJson);
    }

}
```

my next file

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable,FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

import{employee}from'./emp'

@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
  constructor(private db:AngularFireDatabase) 
  { }

  findAllemployees():Observable<employee[]> {
    return this.db.list('/user').map(employee.fromJsonArray);
  }

}
```

error

```js
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable,AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Component, OnInit ,Pipe,PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

import{employee}from'../emp'

import { AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject }           from 'rxjs/Subject';
import{SearchService} from '../search.service';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-searchuser',
  templateUrl: './searchuser.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./searchuser.component.css'],
  providers:[SearchService]

})
export class SearchuserComponent implements OnInit {

  b:employee[];
  heroes: Observable<employee[]>;
  item:FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  i:FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
  constructor( private db:AngularFireDatabase,
    private router: Router,private ser:SearchService) 
  {
    console.log(this.item);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.heroes=this.ser.findAllemployees();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Firebase with something like

**firebase.config.ts**

```
import {AuthMethods, AuthProviders} from 'angularfire2';

export const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: 'blablabla ---- bla',
    authDomain: 'myproject.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://myproject.firebaseio.com',
    storageBucket: 'gs://myproject.appspot.com/',
    messagingSenderId: '123456789'
};



export const authConfig = {
    provider: AuthProviders.Password,
    method: AuthMethods.Password
};
```

The actual parameters to be used in the configuration of Firebase are provided to you when you initialize your project via the Firebase web console (https://console.firebase.google.com).

Ans then, in the **app.module.ts** file, insert

```
  imports: [
    .....
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, authConfig),
    ......
  ],
```

Then in the service class that is using AngularFire I use the following code (this is with AngularFire version angularfire2@2.0.0-beta.8)

```
.....
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';
.....
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  constructor(private af: AngularFire) { }

  loadStuff() {
    return this.af.database.list('/STUFF').map(stuff.fromJsonArray);
  }

...
}
```

Comment: i configured my firebase .. i getting error when i try to bind firebase list variable to observable<employee[]> in jsonarray(method in my program)..else provide some link to how to search heroes (like hero tutorial) in my angular...

Comment: With my version of AngularFire (angularfire2@2.0.0-beta.8) I use a slightly different code - see my updated answer

Comment: im using angularfire 4.0.0 rc 0 ..any  material available for search name (the json like public $key:string,
  public age:number,
  public username: string,
  public email:string,
  public yoe:number